# How to get CPU and Memory usages while learning using Tensorflow 2.X Keras fit()

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras, cpu-usage

I am testing my system for TensorFlow keras machine learning.
This is my testing environments below.

- os : windows10 pro
- tensorflow 2.3
- python 3.7

And here is my code

**[method for cpu and memory usages]**

```
import os
import psutil

def check_cpu_mem():
    cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent()
    memory_usage = psutil.virtual_memory()
    print("- cpu usage : ", cpu_usage, "%")
    print("- memory usage : ", memory_usage, "%")
```

**[call method]**

```
model = get_model(train_input.shape[1], train_input.shape[2], 11)
history = model.fit(train_input, train_output, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)
check_cpu_mem()
```

I call **check_cpu_mem()** after fit.
I think it's not exact information.

How can I get exact usages percentage of CPU and memory while it's running?
I found the way for Linux but not Windows.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/get-hardware-system-information-python) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, but I want to record cpu usage while fit() is running. I think I should find multi thread way. Thank you.